# How do I grab individual tables in R when there are 3 or more classes?

Tags: r

I have a data set that I am trying to find the rand index compared with another data set. One of the sets is shown below. The second set is very similar to this one. I have been trying to use the `classAgreement()` function to get the rand index, however I don't know how to convert the data I have into something that can be used by `classAgreemeent()`. If I can get a table comparing each cluster from each data I think it would help, but I feel lost.

```
-3  6   2
-2  7   2
-5  4   2
-4  7   2
12  10  3
11  9   3
14  11  3
13  12  3
14  18  1
15  19  1
13  20  1
15  16  1
16  18  1
17  17  1
2   10  2
14  9   3
17  6   3
-1  17  2
17  9   3
0   12  2
```

If you run table(mydata) you get three tables for each value of V3 (1, 2 or 3).

```
, , V3 = 1

    V2
V1   4 6 7 9 10 11 12 16 17 18 19 20
  -5 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -4 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -3 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -2 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  11 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  12 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  13 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  14 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
  15 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
  16 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
  17 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0

, , V3 = 2

    V2
V1   4 6 7 9 10 11 12 16 17 18 19 20
  -5 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -4 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -3 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -2 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
  0  0 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  2  0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  11 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  12 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  13 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  14 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  15 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  16 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  17 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

, , V3 = 3

    V2
V1   4 6 7 9 10 11 12 16 17 18 19 20
  -5 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -4 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -3 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -2 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  11 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  12 0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  13 0 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  14 0 0 0 1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
  15 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  16 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  17 0 1 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

How can I work on just one of those produced tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` to select data and provide third position for the table you want to select, for example, to select second table:

```
table(mydata)[,,2]
    V2
V1   4 6 7 9 10 11 12 16 17 18 19 20
  -5 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -4 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -3 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -2 0 0 1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  -1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
  0  0 0 0 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
  2  0 0 0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  11 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  12 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  13 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  14 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  15 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  16 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  17 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```